# ASP.NET HTML5 WebSockets with C# implementation

Tags: asp.net, html, websocket

How to create a simple HTML5 Websockets application using ASP.NET 4.0 (C#).
My problem is about creating Websockets. Below is the code which is tried...

```
try
{
    var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 9988);
    listener.Start();                
    using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake");
        writer.WriteLine("Upgrade: WebSocket");
        writer.WriteLine("Connection: Upgrade");
        writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Origin: http://localhost:9988");
        writer.WriteLine("WebSocket-Location: ws://localhost:8181/websession");
        writer.WriteLine("");
    }
    listener.Stop();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "", ex.Message);
}
```

And the HTML code as follows...!

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var status = '';
        function conStatus(state) {
            return (state == 0) ? 'Connecting..!' : (state == 1) ? 'Opened..!' : (state == 2) ? 'Closing..!' : 'Closed..!';
        }
        function WebSocketTest() {
            if ("WebSocket" in window) {
                try {
                    debugger;
                    var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9988');
                    status += '<br/>Socket Status: ' + conStatus(connection.readyState);

                    connection.onopen = function () {
                        status += 'Socket Opened..!';
                    };

                    connection.onmessage = function () {
                        status += 'Socket received a message..!';
                    };
                    connection.onclose = function () {
                        status += 'Socket Closed..!';
                    };
                    connection.send('Hello World..!');
                }
                catch (exception) {
                    status += '<br/>EXCEPTION: ' + exception;
                }
            }
            else {
                status += "Your Browser does not support WebSockets...!"
            }
            document.write(status);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="sse">
        <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
    </div>
    <div id="status">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If i run this file, the page keeps onloading.. i cant see any result..! Kindly provide me a solution.... Thanks in advance....

Comment: Not actually answering to your question, but do you [SignalR](http://signalr.net)? I belive it supports WebSocket communication and that may wrap the plumbing for you

Comment: he asks for .NET 4.0 ... SignalR requires 4.5 and IIS8 for websocket

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to make a few changes to your server.  It'd be best to start by reading the [handshaking](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2) section of the spec.  At a minimum, you'll need to add a Sec-WebSocket-Accept header to your response.  You could also consider checking Sec-WebSocket-Version and Sec-WebSocket-Protocol in the client request.

After this, you should have a server that'll complete its handshake then immediately close its connection.  You should keep your tcp client alive indefinitely, closing it only when the client closes or requests a close or the server wants to shutdown.

You'll also need to update your client code.  The initial handshake prompted by `new WebSocket(...)` is asynchronous.  You can't use the connection variable until the `onopen` callback runs (so move the `connection.send('Hello World..!')` line there).

After that, you  should read the [data framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.2) section of the spec to see how to send/receive messages.

This adds up to a reasonable chunk of work.  You might find it quicker to use an existing open source server instead.  I haven't used it myself but [Fleck](https://github.com/statianzo/Fleck/) seems to be well regarded and looks like it should be easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

[Websocket](http://pokein.com/Help/WebSocketFeature.aspx) implementation requires more than a simple TcpListener. You may try [PokeIn](http://pokein.codeplex.com) in order to have WebSocket support on all the platforms or you may just update your solution to ASP.NET 4.5 and stick with IIS 8